# How to transfer data using expdp and impdp commands?

Tags: oracle, schema, export, impdp, expdp

I'm an Oracle noob, and my intention is to transfer all data and metadata from one schema to another schema within an Oracle database. I'm planning to use datapump's `expdp` and `impdp` commands. I have questions regarding this:

- Can I create a target schema without a user or should I create a user first (which creates a schema also)?
- Can I execute `expdp` and `impdp` commands using SYS (as sysdba)
  account? Is that a preferred method?
- Does this statement take all the objects (data and metadata) from a schema and move these into a different schema?

  ```
  expdp \"/ as sysdba\" schemas=<schemaname> directory=dumpdir dumpfile=<schemaname>.dmp logfile=expdp_<schemaname>.log
  ```

  So is the target schema an exact copy of the source schema after `impdp` command?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`impdp` will create the user if it's not present yet, so you don't have to worry about it unless that's not what you want.

Do not run `impdb` or `expdp` as **`sysdba`**, only do that if Oracle support requests it in specific circumstances. Use an ordinary user for that - one that has been granted the `dba` role for instance. (There are the [`[IMPORT|EXPORT]_FULL_DATABASE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_overview.htm#CJAIBFJG) privileges specifically for this type of thing, you'll need to grant access to the Oracle directory object(s) too.)

A full schema export (metadata and contents) would indeed look like:

```
expdp user/pass schemas=<schemaname> directory=dumpdir \
      dumpfile=<schemaname>.dmp \
      logfile=expdp_<schemaname>.log
```

If you want to import to a different user/schema (the target database can be the same as the source), you can use:

```
impdp user/pass schemas=schema1 directory=dumpdir \
      remap_schema=schema1:schema2 \
      dumpfile=schema1.dmp \
      logfile=impdp_schema2.log
```

If you don't want a complete import, you can set some filters both on data and metadata. See [Filtering During Import Operations](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_import.htm#i1009204).

The [Utilities Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/toc.htm#BEGIN) has all the details, I strongly recommend reading at least the overview part.

Answer (score 2):

For importing the truncated tables, i.e you only want the data to be imported back to the table:

```
impdp user/pass TABLES=dept DIRECTORY=TEST_dir dumpfile=TEST.dmp logfile=expdpTEST.log TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=REPLACE
```

Above my table is `dept` which I want to import. I have truncated it earlier. From the dumpfile which is `TEST.dmp`, and `logfile` which is `expdpTEST.log` I want only the data to be imported (the table structure will be the same so we use the parameter `TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION`).

If you have truncated 2 tables, for example `emp` and `dept`, and `emp` table has `dept_id` as the foreign key, then you need to import the `dept` table first and then the `emp` table to avoid errors during import.

more info http://satya-dba.blogspot.in/2009/05/datapump.html