# How can i Restore Oracle 12c database Schema from a full EXPDP dump on a Test Server providing a new scheam name?

Tags: oracle, restore, impdp

I have a production database whose full dump is 500Gig and and I cannot do a full restore on a test server because of space issues. However I need to restore a certain schema in from that dump into the Test Server by providing a new Schema Name as part of my restoration Tests.

So how can i do that. The source is 12c Server on Linux and Destination is 12c Server on Linx as well.

Comment: Do you have to use *this* dump file?

Comment: Yes, The audit requirement is that we do a full restore quarterly and test but however because of space constraints i wanted to do a schema restore from the September 30 full.dmp

Comment: Umm..`expdb` is NOT a backup. Oracle license has restrictions on how often you can test your (RMAN) backups each year without licensing the server you're testing the backup on...and it defines how long you can run your tests. Beyond that, your recovery test server needs to be properly licensed.

Comment: expdp is a logical backup of the data, not a physical backup of the database instance like rman. Each can have a place in your overall disaster recovery plan, but be clear what that place is and what the limitations are (especially of expdp). You can restore to a different schema using the remap_schema directive.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to transfer data using expdp and impdp commands?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30516/how-to-transfer-data-using-expdp-and-impdp-commands)

Answer (score 0):

You can import only single schema from your dump file by using "schemas" parameter. Also, you can import the schema into non-original name.

For example, if you want to import schema MY_SCHEMA into MY_NEW_SCHEMA use this command:

```
impdp system/password dumpfile=full.dmp logfile=full.imp_log schemas=MY_SCHEMA remap_schema=MY_SCHEMA:MY_NEW_SCHEMA
```

Omit `remap_schema` if you want to import into the same schema